# Can't install Apache2 and PHP in Linux Mint 17.3 (libapache2-mod-php)

Tags: apt, php, apache-httpd

Apache2 and PHP are correctly installed, but `libapache2-mod-php` is giving problems.

I try to install it with `apt-get` and I get the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnupg : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: apache2-api-20120211
                       Depends: apache2 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ucf but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
 libuuid1 : Depends: passwd
 libuuid1:i386 : Depends: passwd:i386
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I try to install each package, but says that they are already installed.

I also try to install the module with aptitude, for which I get the following output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php5
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2.212 kB of archives. After unpacking 9.897 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg : Breaks: libapache2-mod-php5 (< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17 is to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libapache2-mod-php5 [Not Installed]                



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

I select Yes, but nothing is installed; after restarting Apache, my `phpinfo` page is not working.

This is the output of `uname -a`, if it is useful:

```
Linux julen-Surface-Pro-3 4.4.6-3-surface #tigerite ZEN SMP Tue May 24 13:22:59 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT**: the output of `apt-cache policy dpkg`:

```
dpkg:
  Installed: 1.17.25ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.17.25ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.17.25ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/mint-xorg-update/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.17.5ubuntu5.6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.17.5ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tigerlite's [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/mint-xorg-update) includes an updated `dpkg` (presumably for valid reasons), but it doesn't include updates to [other packages](https://salsa.debian.org/dpkg-team/dpkg/commit/ec6334a744a54ce7051937a0f94d830cb32bcb43) that updated `dpkg` breaks. These broken packages include `libapache2-mod-php5`...

So ideally you should ask tigerlite to add the relevant, updated packages to his PPA.

Alternatively, if you're feeling adventurous you could try downgrading `dpkg` to the Ubuntu 14.04 version:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg=1.17.5ubuntu5.6
```

If that works without forcing anything, you should be OK. Downgrades aren't officially supported in Debian packages though, so this will not have been tested at all; and since it's `dpkg` we're talking about it may well break your package management entirely.

Comment: The downgrading worked like a charm, and allowed to install the module. Many thanks.